# What is the full chain list of formats that Android .java file is getting through?

Tags: java, android, dex, smali

I just noticed the .smali file, which the .dex file is compiled to.
I want to be able to track over all the transformations that my .java file is going through.

First, I want to know what are all the transformation that executed from creation of the .java file to the .apk that I install.

Second, How can I actually see and open all those files that created in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no time in the standard Android build process is a .smali file produced. This is a custom disassembly format not used by Google. I assume you disassembled an APK. The usual code-related files involved in the [standard tool chain](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) are java -> class -> (sometimes jar ->) dex -> APK.